# Play Store Release Notes: Only one default translations possible?

Tags: android, google-play

**Problem:**

When releasing a new version into Play Store I am forced to add translations for all languages.

**Question:**

I would like to only add one default translation for all languages.

**Details:**

- My apps needs multiple translations of the Play Store entry. Thus, I cannot remove other translations from the whole App description section.
- Current workaround is to copy+paste the default translation into all `<en-EN></><de-DE></><it-IT></>` etc. sections, which is kind of inefficient ;-)
- In the following (sorry, German) screenshot you can see that the Play Store does not like release notes without `<en-EN>` etc. sections.:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple: provide the release note only for your app's primary language (e.g. English) and it will display in all other regions.

(you are not forced to provide translations for all supported languages)

Comment: Wow. Too simple. I guess I always tried with another language (only) as I didn't know what my "default language" was :-) Thanks a lot! Play Store could have, however, shown a more helpful error / description.